# Adjoint of operators with dense range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hilbert spaces and $A:X\to Y$ be a linear bounded operator. Assume further that range of $A$ is dense in $Y$. Is the operator $A^*$ bounded?

Comment: The operator $A^*$ is bounded by virtue of $A$ being bounded, irrespective of the denseness of range.

Comment: How do you define $A^*$ over $Y\backslash range(A)$?

Comment: The following formula defines $A^*:Y\to X$, $\langle A^* y, x\rangle_X = \langle y, Ax\rangle_Y$ for all $y\in Y, x\in X$. From this you can read off $\|A^*y\|≤ \|A\|\,\|y\|$ and then $\|A^*\|≤\|A\|$. The other inequality ($\|A\|≤\|A^*\|$) als holds, in this case because $A^{**}=A$.